# How to avoid the buffer mechanism from FileSystem

Tags: c, filesystems, buffer, virtualbox

**Take VirtualBox's virtual disk as example**:if VirtualBox didn't avoid the buffer mechanism  from FileSystem in host os,the FileSystem in guest os would move data from memory to meory.

In fact ,I want to write **a filesystem in user space(put all directorys and files in a single big file)**. But if I use **c api such fread and fwrite** ,the FileSystem in os would buffer the data that My UserSpace-FileSystem read、write.But My UserSpace-FileSystem has implement a buffer mechanism by itself.If i didn't avoid the buffer mechanism from FileSystem in os,My UserSpace-FileSystem would move data from memory to memory.It's so bad .

Dose anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stdio` doesn't support that.

For *NIX: [`man open`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) for O_DIRECT, [`man fadvise`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fadvise) and [`man madvise`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise).

For Windows, check the [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) for `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`. Probably a good idea to dig the [`CreateFileMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) too.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear, but if all you want to do is use `stdio` without buffering, then `setbuf(file, NULL);` will solve your problem. A better solution might be to avoid `stdio` entirely and use lower-level io primitives `read`, `write`, etc. (not part of plain C but specified by POSIX, and with nearly-equivalent versions of them available on most non-POSIX systems too).

Comment: It seem like lower-level io will buffer stream too.
Thanks also.

Comment: That's a separate layer of buffering which you generally should not try to avoid, although some misguided application vendors go to great lengths to do it... most infamously, Oracle.